# Why is there one broken note in the opening music of The Silence of the Lambs?

Tags: soundtrack, the-silence-of-the-lambs

There are two broken notes in the opening music for the movie *The Silence of the Lambs*. I have purchased the HD4k version of this movie from iTunes and it has exactly the same broken note.

The background music is eerie enough to set up the mood for this movie, I am wondering why there is a broken note.

[0:32~0:34 is there the broken note is, I feel a note is missing on 0:33 of this trailer.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbZOk1nU_R0)

Comment: I'm not sure what a broken note is and the music doesn't sound strange to me at all.

Comment: I see what you mean. There is a very out of place note. I would call it a “bum note”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing 'missing' at all - the track does this several times; just your ear has got used to it by the 2nd or 3rd time. This one feels odd because it's the first one that really establishes the 'beat'.

The bar before ends with a string line descending through 3, 4, then there's a bass note [really a low-voiced chord] on beat 1, with a broader spread of the full chord following on the 2. The next 6 or 8 bars don't emphasise that push quite so much, but you hear it again a couple of times by the time she reaches the top of the hill.

This is just 4 bars from just before 0:30 to just after - a piano score so not exactly the same as the soundtrack - with the push circled.

[image]

I think if you want a more detailed explanation, then [Music Practise & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions) would be a better place.

Comment: Yeah. It's a stylistic method.